# Listener for lazy-loading fields in JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to add a custom listener/hook which would be triggered after loading a lazy field of an entity (e.g. `@OneToMany` collection) where you can put your custom code?

I can imagine something similar to `@PostLoad` annotation but which would be triggered later, at the 1st access to the lazy field.

No biggie if it's possible but without reference to the concrete field.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provides this through the Event Listener. The `EventType` is `INIT_COLLECTION`

Please read the documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-event-listener-registration

Comment: Does it work for non-collection types (e.g. a parent entity reference with `@ManyToOne`)?

Comment: If had a look at the code but I can't find one for ToMany relationships because this is done via byte code enhancement